# Editing a torrent's magnet link

Tags: utorrent, links, magnet-links

Is there a way to make a magnet link for downloading specific files of a torrent, for example : adding something to the link to specify (select) the files to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a way to make a magnet link for downloading specific files of a torrent?

No. Magnet links don't know anything about files in the torrent.

> A magnet link is essentially a hyperlink containing the hash code for
>   that torrent, which your torrent client can immediately use to start
>   finding people sharing those files. Magnet links don't require a
>   tracker (since it uses DHT, which you can read more about [here](http://lifehacker.com/5411311/bittorrents-future-dht-pex-and-magnet-links-explained)), nor
>   does it require you to download a separate file before starting the
>   download, which is convenient.

Source [What Are Magnet Links, and How Do I Use Them to Download Torrents?](https://lifehacker.com/5875899/what-are-magnet-links-and-how-do-i-use-them-to-download-torrents)